# Removing header and footer

Tags: pandas, data-science

How can I remove the header and footer when using pandas.read_excel? I do not have any knowledge of how many rows need to be excluded because the file is altered frequently and information of editors may be added to the header/footer sections otherwise would have gone with something else.

Comment: What is a _footer_?

Comment: This is too less a info to suggest anything. Please provide more details.

Comment: I do not have more information since the file I want to work with is regularly updated and the header and footer might be altered.